# Is the Rescue Armor based on the same Nanotech as Tony's Mark LXXXV?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Is it ever mentioned if the **Rescue armor** Tony designed specifically for Pepper Potts in *Avengers: Endgame* was nanotech as well?

Also, **Mark LXXXV** (*Mark 85*) was based on **Advanced Nano-Tech Armor** (mentioned [here](https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_LXXXV)) whereas its predecessor, **Mark L** (*Mark 50*) in *Avengers: Infinity War* was simply **Nano-Tech Suit** (mentioned [here](https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_L)).

So if Rescue was nanotech, was it based on Mark 50's version of nanotech or Mark 85's?

Answer (score 3):

The suit is certainly one of the nanotech suits as we see Pepper "unfold" her helmet when she lands by Peter for the girl power team up for transporting the Stark Gauntlet.

[image: Pepper's helmet unfolds showing the nanotech]

It isn't clear what version of suit Pepper's was designed off of, however, it was being designed by Tony when Cap, Natasha and Scott come to meet him at his house.

> **Tony Stark:** You should not be wearing that, okay? That is part of a special anniversary gift I'm making for Mom.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

As such it is certainly designed off of one of the later suits from somewhere between the Mark 50 and Mark 85 presumably nearer the latter. It is probably safe to assume it is designed off of the Mark 85 but as we don't know when it was designed we can't say for sure.

Pepper's Rescue suit also has the similar functionality of both of the suits where it can create external parts for different functionalities as we see her doing this in the battle.